# Docker image check before deploying to Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Assume I have a deployment/Pod with lets say a name "xyz" . I would like to check if this Pod has a specific image. If this image is different from what I have recently pulled from the docker registry only then deploy. Otherwise don't deploy.
This is assuming that the tags are not updated. any ideas appreciated.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment Quoting: **A Deployment’s rollout is triggered if** and only if the Deployment’s pod template (that is, .spec.template) is changed, for example if **the labels or container images of the template are updated.**

Answer (score 1):

Check this out this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266006/how-do-i-redeploy-everything-in-kubernetes-after-updating-a-dockerfile/46266696#46266696) is based on rolling update mechanism. Or directly set using the command line tool as kubectl,

```
$ kubectl set image deployment/auth-deployment auth=auth:2.1.0
```

Then you can simply check the status and deployment respectively to get the change by the above rollout. Details is in the link of comment given by Genti Saliu.

Note that a rollout process will trigger only and only if deployment's pod template is changed i.e. `.spec.template` is changed. Using the above `set` command will not guarantee a uptime until the rollout process is complete. So, it's just user in your dev environment.

For no downtime you have have to use the proper strategy as one below,

```
minReadySeconds: 7
strategy:
  type: RollingUpdate
  rollingUpdate:
    maxSurge: 1
    maxUnavailable: 1
```

As long as the `maxUnavailable` is set to zero, no existing pod will be replaced until the new pod was instantiated after `minReadySeconds` time over. This will not give any downtime. Hope this helps.

Comment: If I set the image to a new one,in the deployment will it cause a downtime?

Comment: @sbolla: yes, I updated the answer as per your question.